# Can't get .php to output to the browser

Tags: php

I am completely new to coding and my current assignment is just to use a "here document" block.  All the code I have for the program is:

```php
<?php
$firstphpstring = <<<ONTOTHENEXTONE 
I have now coded my first block to be displayed
in my very first web page.I am excited to see what the 
next several weeks have in stored.
ONTOTHENEXTONE;

echo $firstphpstring;
?>
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in > C:\wamp\www\php_foothill\Week2Lab_CIS052N_heredoc_gettype.php on line 2

I am using Windows 7, WAMPServer 2.2, and have the .php file in a folder in C:\wamp\www

Comment: Did you get this all working?

Answer (score 7):

Remove the space after the `<<<ONTOTHENEXTONE`.

Comment: @LandinMartens: Yeah, I don't usually select lines as a first course of action :)

Comment: @minitech always select and highlight heredoc strings on SO! It's nearly always a space after the starting delimiter or space before the ending one...

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I removed the space after the delimiter, but now I get this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\php_foothill\Week2Lab_Prog1_heredoc.php on line 9

Comment: @jimmyjohns: Make sure there are no spaces or tabs before or after the `ONTOTHENEXTONE;`